# Kali linux stuck on booting

Tags: boot, kali-linux

I'm trying to install Kali linux on my laptop, but after successful installation, it's freezes on booting. here is screenshot:
[image]

So, how can I fix this? Also I'm unable to enter in any of tty modes, in this point my laptop is completely freeze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to boot it with `nomodeset` parameter in the grub settings? The GPU is often the reason.

Comment: How can I edit grub settings during boot?

Comment: When you'll see a boot menu, press 'e' and add "nomodeset" after "rw quiet"

Comment: Hmmm.... That's works, thank you!!! But can you explain little bit more, what causing freezing?

Comment: I had also stucked with it before and I fould this solution on some forum. The reason is in gpu driver conflict. After you install distro you'll need to find a right driver for your gpu.

Comment: Most likely you have intel+nvidia laptop. Nouveau driver always cause some problems

Comment: Yeap, its intel/nvidia, anyway thank you, you solved my problem. I will try to install correct drivers.